# undefined method `content_for' in presenter rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I am using a presenter for a view in rails to display data which is saved in a yml file. (i18n gem)

This is the controller-

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @presenter = DocumentPresenter.new
  end
end
```

This is my view-

```
= @presenter.viewname
```

and  this is my presenter-

```
class DocumentPresenter
  def viewname
    content_for :secondary_nav_title do
      t('Documents')
    end
  end
end
```

The error says:

> undefined method `content_for'

Why doesn't rails recognize `content_for` in the presenter?

Answer (score 0):

the content_for helper method should not be used in your model as this violates the MVC pattern.

if you must use it, though this is not reccomended, you can add this at the bottom of your model.

```
def helpers 
    ActionController::Base.helpers
end
```

Then to call content_for you would use

```
class DocumentPresenter
  def viewname
      helpers.content_for :secondary_nav_title do
         t('Documents')
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: I am not using content_for in the model. I am using it in my presenter. The problem seem to be in the presenter. Rails is not recognizing content_for in the presenter for some reason. Am I calling it right?

Comment: This soulution should still work, try adding the def helpers at the end of your presenter and calling it in the way shown above

Comment: That worked good. There still seems to be a problem when I try to access the values through t('Documents'). Do i need to add a helper for that too?