# How to vary the title of a page when using layouts and partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following this tutorial (https://www.railstutorial.org/book/rails_flavored_ruby), I wish to vary the title of a layout based on the controller.

I have my page in four sections which I can change at will.  It is working well excpet I am having a hard time changing the title.

Here is my layout:

```
<html>
<head>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "ERP" %>

    <title><%= yield(:title) %></title>

</head>
<body>

    <%= render 'header' %>
    <%= render "sidebar" %>
    <%= render "content" %>
    <%= render "footer" %>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to add the title in the controller but it did not work:

```
class ViewerController < ApplicationController

   def index

        provide(:title, "Viewer")

   end

   def update

   end

end
```

I get the error "undefined method `provide' for #".  We will have more apps that use the same layout, changing what sections they need to.  I would like to change the title based on the app.

Anyone know how I can use the provide function in a controller?

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for in your controller is not `provide` but:

```
content_for :title, 'Viewer'
```

[API Docs content_for v. provide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-provide)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Unfortunately I tried 'content_for :title, 'Viewer'' and received "undefined method `content_for' "  Then I searched but could not find any examples other than the one you posted.  So I used the alternate syntax, not knowing what is wrong, 'content_for(:title) || "Viewer"' but this failed with the same error.  Tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116785/undefined-method-content-for-in-presenter-rails although it does not make an error :title does not get set.  Is there an alternate method to accomplish this goal?
'