# How to dynamically display a custom title when using a layout and partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a layout and partials that are working fine.  The problem is different models all have the same title.  If would be nice if I can customize the title for each model.

This is my layout:

```
<html>
<head>

    <title><%= content_for :title %></title>

</head>
<body>

    <%= render 'header' %>
    <%= render "sidebar" %>
    <%= render "content" %>
    <%= render template: "layouts/footer" %>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller I tried making work based on [undefined method `content_for' in presenter rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116785/undefined-method-content-for-in-presenter-rails):

```
class ViewerController < ApplicationController

   def index

        helpers.content_for :title, "Viewer"
        #helpers.content_for (:title)  "Viewer" #doesn't work

   end

    def helpers 

        ActionController::Base.helpers      

    end

end
```

I tried changing the layout to <%= helpers.content_for :title %> but it did not work.  I also tried changing the controller to helpers.content_for (:title)  "Viewer" and elpers.content_for (:title) || "Viewer" based on other posts but they fail.

If this approach does not work then I am open to another.

Comment: I've found if I have a single line in index.html.erb with the code "<% provide(:title, "Viewer") %>" it does work.  I didn't know a html.erb file will execute even if its not being displayed in the layout with <%= yield %>.  Is this design clean?  I will post it as the solution unless someone points out something better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails: How to change the title of a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185965/rails-how-to-change-the-title-of-a-page)

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.  Here is my layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>

    <title><%= yield :title %></title>

</head>
<body>

    <%= render 'header' %>
    <%= render "sidebar" %>    
    <%= render "content" %>
    <%= render template: "layouts/footer" %>

</body>
```

Here is my view (index.html.erb):

```
<% provide(:title, "Viewer") %>
```

I did not know the erb will execute even if it is not called to be displayed anywhere.  I do not have a <%= yeild %> anywhere.  I can put HTML in there and no one will ever see it.  But the ruby code will execute.

Answer (score 1):

In application_helper.rb add the following code:

```
def full_title(page_title = '')                    
  base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" 
  if page_title.empty?                             
    base_title                                     
  else
    page_title + " | " + base_title
  end                 
end
```

Add following code in application.html.erb file:

```
<title><%= full_title(@title) %></title>
```

And in controller you can then assign value to instance variable like this on any of the routes methods e.g. index:

```
@title = "Home"
```

But it is not a good idea to use an instance variable to show the title.

Comment: This does not work since there are no individual pages, just the layout.  I tried provide(:title, "Home") in the controller but it does not work.

Comment: provide(:title, "Home") wont work in controller, it is for view only. If you want to set the title from the controller you have to use instance variable

Comment: OK, so how do I make an instance variable to just display the title?

Answer (score 0):

Your layout should be `yield :title` instead of `content_for :title`. In this way, for your controllers you can just do as you are already doing correctly, and that is setting the content for the layout to be their respective titles.

With `yield: title` you are practically doing the same thing as `render`, except it is handled by the other controllers/views/models.

Comment: yield: title does not work without <% provide(:title, "Home") %>.  And provide(:title, "Home") does not work in the controller.